# How to add an arrow icon in a round rect button

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am trying to put an arrow sign in the round rect button. I intend to use it as a reverse/undo button.. How do go about to do it?

is it something like this?

```
- (IBAction)ReversePressed:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it custom. if you want to make its corners round, import QuartzCore framework, add it to your .h or .m file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>:
```

and in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // this is the code to make the button's corners round        
    [button setCornerRadius:cornerRadiusParam];
    [button setMasksToBounds:YES];

}
```

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` or wherever your are creating your buttons

Comment: no no. The code I posted is for button setup. The method that gets called when that button is pressed is another thing. That's what you need to take care of.

Comment: Sorry i am a bit blur... where exactly?

Comment: can u edit it in your answer... i think it will be useful for those reading next time as well..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer is to use a Unicode character.  For example you could use U+21B6 ↶ ANTICLOCKWISE TOP SEMICIRCLE ARROW (type `@"\u21b6"` in your source code).  Or you could use U+21E6 ⇦ LEFTWARDS WHITE ARROW.  [This PDF](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2190.pdf) shows the Unicode Arrows character range.  You can also use the Mac OS X character viewer to browse them.

If you are willing to require iOS 5, there is also the Emoji character ⬅.

Comment: so it goes UIButton *button = @"\u21b6";?

Comment: No.  You have to set the button's `titleLabel.text` property.  You will probably also want to set the button's `titleLabel.font` property to adjust the size of the arrow.

Comment: There are many tutorials on the net that cover this.  Apple has lots of documentation.  You need to do some reading and work through some tutorials.